# Updating state from Formik onSubmit handler causing useEffect to fire twice

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, formik

In this code, Formik onSubmit calls a function and the function updates two pieces of state. These two pieces are both parameters on a useEffect and it causes the useEffect to log "updated" twice.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Formik, Form } from "formik";

export default function App() {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState(1);
  const [bar, setBar] = useState("a");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("updated");
  }, [foo, bar]);

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    setFoo(2);
    setBar("b");
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Formik initialValues={{ test: "123" }} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Form>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </Form>
      </Formik>
      {foo}
      {bar}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Testable version:
https://codesandbox.io/s/async-dew-eri87?file=/src/App.js

This is the same piece of code but uses a regular form instead of Formik. This time on submit "updated" is only being called once:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState(1);
  const [bar, setBar] = useState("a");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("updated");
  }, [foo, bar]);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setFoo(2);
    setBar("b");
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      {foo}
      {bar}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Testable version:
https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-fermat-wk0ul?file=/src/App.js:0-491

Why is the Formik version making the useEffect run twice and is there a way to make it only run once?

Answer (score 0):

I think its behaving as it should, since the dependencies are foo and bar, every time one of them changes, then the useEffect fires. I would suggest having another flag to trigger the update when necessary, and resetting the flag on run. the useEffect runs twice again and the setUpdate method is run within the useEffect, but because it will be false, it will stop there

You can read more about it here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Formik, Form } from "formik";

export default function App() {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState(1);
  const [bar, setBar] = useState("a");
  const [update, setOnUpdate] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (update) {
      console.log("updated");
      setOnUpdate(false);
    }
  }, [update]);

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    setFoo(2);
    setBar("b");
    setOnUpdate(true);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Formik initialValues={{ test: "123" }} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Form>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </Form>
      </Formik>
      {foo}
      {bar}
    </div>
  );
}
```